# Switch text direction to right-to-left in Chrome under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, right-to-left

In Chrome under Windows, I can press right control+right shift and the text direction in text fields and text boxes becomes right-to-left. But under Ubuntu, nothing happens.

In other programs (Gedit for example,) I can right-click then select `Insert Unicode Control Character`->`RLM Right-to-left Mark` to change the text direction, but that menu is not present when I right-click a text box in Chrome.

How can I change the text direction in Chrome?

Edit:
I tried Manually inserting a RLM Mark (a list is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters#Bidirectional_text_control)) by holding control+shift then typing `u` followed by the hex code of the control character. Out of the seven listed (U+200E, U+200F, U+202A, U+202B, U+202C, U+202D, U+202E), three of them (U+200F, U+202B, U+202E) worked in Gedit, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [this open source extension](https://chrome.Google.com/extensions/detail/fldkjfjmcadcklboajlnclnfjpdopcce) provides a switch direction button that will added to your Google chrome and can switch text edits direction in any OS.

*Disclaimer:* I am publisher of the extension.

**Update:** Chrome now itself provides similar functionality on text edits context menu thus makes such extension somehow useless.

Comment: yes, @ebraminio: it was automatically deleted because it looked spammy.  If this is your product/software, clearly say so.

Comment: yes. but this is not a product, just a simple extension :)

Comment: Thanks, I had given up on this (The question was asked more than half a year ago).

Comment: What about Firefox?

Comment: On Firefox, you can use Ctrl+Shift+X (or Alt? I don't remember) or double Right/Left Ctrl+Shift there after enabling browser.bidi.ui https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1128107

Answer (score 5):

Couple of guesses - does either <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Right SHIFT</kbd>, or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> work?

There are some subtle differences in Linux Chrome due to the use of GTK controls.

Comment: Nope, they don't work.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+X works splendidly for me in Firefox, which is what I was looking for now, since I accidentally switched it and didn't know how to get it back.  Thanks!

Comment: What about Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

- For left-to-right direction >> **Right Ctrl + Left Shift**
- For right-to-left direction >> **Right Ctrl + Left Shift**

Answer (score -1):

I made an extension for chrome that solves this problem. you are welcome to use it. you can add it to chrome on here: chrome://extensions/ and active devloper mode
https://github.com/Guyc1800/switch-input-direction-for-linux/tree/main

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please clarify: how is this answer better than the accepted one? The poster of the question has already accepted an answer as solving his problem.

Comment: @DarkDiamond actually it is simple and it works better then the suggested answers.

Comment: @GuyCohen - **Except it appears somebody already suggested that extension 11 years ago.**  Let me clarify, an extension, with the exact same name.  Your repository is a couple of hours old is suspect which is the reason the community would love for you to explain why your solution is a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound it cant be the same extenstion because I wrote this extension yesterday. yesterday I learned how to code extensions for chrome. if you would look at the code you will see they dont share any similarty at all. also one of the problems I had with the already suggested extension is that the only available shortcut for switching direction was ctrl+shift+otherletter(x is defeult) diffrent from windows where you simply use Rctrl+Rshift for RTL and Lctrl+Lshift for LTR, my extension solve this problem by using content_scripts. just look at the code before you make  assumption